# MS Test: Getting executing testlocation?

Tags: c#, mstest

How do I find the equivalent of a path to the executing assembly when running tests under MS Test in VS 2010? I need to know where the test is running from, so that I can set a relative path to a data file that it needs.

I am trying to find the same sort of path to an executing test that I would get if I used `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` on an executing assembly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`TestContext.DeploymentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.deploymentdirectory.aspx) to get the test deployment directory. The test configuration allows you to [automatically deploy files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182475.aspx) for tests.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the 'automatically deploy files' link. I'm learning MS Test, and that was a very helpful link. I'm starting to see things that MS Test can do that other frameworks can't.

Comment: This is only true if MSTest deployment is in effect. If no test uses `DeploymentItemAttribute`, or if `<DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>` is included in your `.runsettings` file, MSTest deployment does not take place and your tests will execute directly from the build output folder. Using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` as Nikita suggested below works in both cases, as does `Environment.CurrentDirectory` (which I don't like as much as it's easy to change).

Comment: In MSTest2 there is no DeploymentDirectory property. Consider other answers

Answer (score 11):

This question is not specific to MsTest. You can use the same solution you would use in any other .NET application.

An answer from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295694/182371):

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the assembly for the current test.

See [How to get the assembly (System.Reflection.Assembly) for a given type in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141121/how-to-get-the-assembly-system-reflection-assembly-for-a-given-type-in-net)