# File.ReadAllText throws DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#

I have a block of C# code that is trying to open a .txt file. This text file is in the same project as the block of code that's running. At this time, I'm trying to open the .txt file using the following:

```
var filePath = @"\Status\new.txt";
try 
{
    var content= File.ReadAllText(filePath);
} 
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to find " + filePath);
}
```

When this code runs, I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException`. The console shows:

> Unable to find \Status\new.txt

I changed the "Copy to Output Directory" property of the "new.txt" file to "Copy if newer". I can see the "new.txt" file in the "bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Status/" directory.

I'm running this code currently via an MSTest project. I don't understand why I'm getting this exception though.

Comment: print the exception, see the full path that it can't find.

Comment: ReadAllText probably needs a full path

Comment: try removing the first slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\Status\new.txt` will try to load, from the root of the disk, `new.txt` in the `status` directory. From your description, this isn't where the file is.

If you have the file in the same folder as your executable you only need the `new.txt`, if it's in a subdirectory off of where the executable is, then `.\status\new.txt` should work.

Comment: I'm not sure about `.\status\new.txt`. According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710167/ms-test-getting-executing-testlocation) `Path.Combine(TestContext.DeploymentDirectory, "Status", "new.txt")` or `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Status", "new.txt")` looks safer.